# How to get DataTextField(Content) of DropDownBox in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

I am working on a classic ASP web application. I have dropdownbox where a user can select more than one item and submit the form . Now my requirement is that
how to get content of DropDownBox (need to  insert into database table both content and value where value is table ID(primary key)  )

for example

```
 <option value="1">ABC</option>
 <option value="2">XYZ</option>
 <option value="3">MNO</option>
 --------
 --------
 --------
 <option value="100">DEF</option>
```

After user submit the page how can i get content of selected dropdown items.

I can get value by writing: item =request.form("data") So how to get content of selected items

Comment: You get the content the same way you wrote out the dropdown in the first place. :)

Comment: The form submits to other form and I am loading initial data into dropdown box from database table

Comment: So you get the selected indexes from the form, and then you get their values from the database table. Like I said, same way you generated it in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple-select listboxes, `Request.Form` will contain a comma-separated list of values selected. For example, if the following options were chosen:

```
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="3">MNO</option>
```

`Request.Form(<name of select element>)` would contain:

```
1, 3
```

So you can `Split()` the value to get an array of selected options:

```
a = Split(Request.Form("whatever"), ",")

For Each o In a
    Response.Write "Selected value = " & o & "<br>"
Next
```

**Edit**:

Sounds like you'll need to do something like this:

```
<option value="1-ABC">ABC</option>
<option value="2-XYZ">XYZ</option>
<option value="3-MNO">MNO</option>
```

Then use code similar to what's posted above but also `Split()` on `o` to separate the ID from the text:

```
a = Split(Request.Form("whatever"), ",")

Dim o, id, text
For Each o In a
    id = Split(o, "-")(0)
    text = Split(o, "-")(1)

    Response.Write "Selected value = " & id & ", text = " & text & "<br>"
Next
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes you are correct but I want content of drop down list not value

Comment: Oh, I see. That's a bit unusual. You would typically assign whatever value you want to retrieve to the `value` attribute. Couldn't you just assign the text value to the `value` attribute? `<option value="ABC">ABC</option>` if you don't plan on using the numbers for anything.

Comment: i need to insert this data(both value of dropdown and content of dropdown ) into database table so here the value is primary key in table

Comment: OK. I've updated my answer. Do you think that would work for you?

Comment: So I cannot assign content of dropdown to value property

Comment: Are you asking if you can or are you saying you cannot?

Comment: Oh!yeah thanks I am thinking of doing same way as well . Thanks a lot that'll will suffiesmy requirement

Comment: Cool. Just make sure to use a delimiter that won't appear in your text/content. A dash (`-`) may not be the best choice for that.

Answer (score 0):

After some double-checking, I don't believe it's possible to grab the text from a dropdown item using ASP Classic's `request` object.  Since you included the ASP.NET tag, if you're using that, the text is a property off of the control:

```
// Gets the value of the dropdown item
nameOfDropDown.SelectedItem.Value

// Gets the text of the dropdown item
nameOfDropDown.SelectedItem.Text
```

If you're needing a workaround for ASP Classic, you can fill an array with the same data in the dropdown as a mapping object.  After the user submits the form, you can index into the array using the value(s) return in the request's form data to retrieve the text value.

```
//Assuming VB when using ASP Classic
//Also assuming a method that returns the values for your dropdown
Dim dropDownArray() = MethodToReturnArrayOfDropDownText()

//Using your snippet for getting the dropdown value
Dim item = request.form("data")

//Use that value to get the text out of the array
Dim selectedText = dropDownArray(item)
```

Note, depending on the language backing the array, you may have to adjust to either 0- or 1-based arrays.  You will also have to loop through the returned form data if the dropdown is multi-selectable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.How can i access the array in second form

Comment: do you want me to save array in session object  for further access or is there any better and efficient way.

Comment: If you're required to work with ASP Classic, session is your best bet for keeping that mapping object around for reference

Comment: i suppose he tagged ASP.NET by mistake